# Error running Jupyter Notebook on windows with python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I get the following error when trying to run jupyter notebook.
It is a fresh install of python and jupyter notebook.

[image]

Comment: What's in the notebook?

Comment: @Dbercules it is a fresh install

Comment: Please paste the text of the traceback.

Comment: @krassowski
It's in the image attached. Cannot paste logs in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `nbjson.py` is trying to import the function `encodestring()` from `base64`. That function has been [deprecated since Python 3.1](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/base64.html) (2009) and was removed in Python 3.9. The Python 3 name for the function is `encodebytes()`.

Unless you feel up to remediating legacy code in a 3rd-party module (something I would hesitate to recommend), your options are (1) report the problem to the `nbjson` maintainer or (2) install Python 3.8 alongside Python 3.9 for this project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did not want to downgrade the python version which is why I asked the question here but it looks like this is the only way!

Comment: You don't have to *downgrade*. Just install the older version alongside the one you have.